# GCC run assembly program mac?

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, terminal

I am attempting to run the following code in terminal on my Mac:

```
.section, .data

format_string:
   .asciz "My favorite number is %d!"

number:
  .long 786

.section, .text
.globl main

main:
  pushl number
 pushl $format_string  
 call printf 
  addl $8, %esp

  pushl $0
  call exit
```

This code is in a file named favorite.s

I used the command "gcc favorite.s -m32" and am seeing the following message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
  "exit", referenced from:
      main in ccUKdD8O.o
  "printf", referenced from:
      main in ccUKdD8O.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Symbols have an underscore prepended to them on Mac OS X.  Add a `_` in front of `main`, `exit`, and `printf` in your program and try again!

Comment: After adding that I am now getting an output that says "Illegal instruction: 4" :/

Comment: Sounds like a typo somewhere.  Can you show your updated code?

Comment: I tried a simpler program and it produces that same message:

.section, .text 
.globl _main 

_main: 
# Pass one parameter to exit. 
pushl $27 
call _exit

Comment: Wait - at compile time or runtime?  Are you running into this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177038/illegal-instruction-4-shows-up-in-os-x-lion?

Comment: It compiles.  The message comes up when i do ./a.out.  I tried adding that -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 when i did gcc favorite.s -m32, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Does the disassembly match your source?  What happens when you step through in your debugger?  I'm afraid I don't have a computer handy, so I can't test it out for you here.